# Trying to install autoconf dependencies without root permissions

Tags: linux, macros, xorg, autoconf

so this is just a part of my grand installation of i3 on a school Linux PC. I'm trying to compile i3 myself and install it in my home directory. I just used my home directory as a prefix for everything, so I have the folders `~/bin`, `~/share` and `~/lib` where all the installations go in.

Now, for one package I tried to install (`inputproto`), I got the error

```
configure.ac:7: error: must install xorg-macros 1.10 or later before running autoconf/autogen
configure.ac:7: the top level
```

So I went ahead, looked up what `xorg-macros` is, and found out it's a part of `xutils-dev`. I downloaded that and ran the configuration file in `xutils-dev-7.7+5/util-macros` with the correct prefix. Then I ran `make`, which gave me an error (something about permissions). I looked into the Makefile and saw that the prefix wasn't set. So I just set it manually, ran `make` and `make install` and there were no more warnings or errors. I now have a file called `~/share/aclocal/xorg-macros.m4`

This is precisely what autoconf was asking for, right? But if I now run

```
autoconf -I ~/share/aclocal
```

I still get the same error as before. Does anyone have a clue what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

There was an `autogen.sh` inside that went completely over my head. I only had to edit one line so that the call of `autoreconf` uses my prefix, and then everything worked with

```
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=~
make
make install
```